# Is there a book with 100 reductions?

Tags: reductions, reference-request, books, polynomial-time-reductions

In a lecture I'm taking about complexity theory a professor said, there are infinite many NP-complete problems.

##### Question:

I was wondering if there exists something like a database or a book with some known reductions (or with maybe more than only the NP-complete ones) and the proofs for them?  I know there is a very nice [database for Rings](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/rings/), but I couldn't find something similar for reductions.

Comment: As a side note:

There is an infinite number of $NP$-complete problems. Simply take your favorite $NP$-complete problem, and call it $L$. For any $k\ge 0$ we have that $0^kL$ is also $NP$-complete. Since we can choose an infinite number of $k$'s, we also must have an infinite number of $NP$-complete problems.

Comment: Ahm yes...I've edited my question :)

Comment: Though not containing the actual reductions, the standard reference is [Garey & Johnson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computers_and_Intractability).

Comment: An interactive database of reductions similar to [ISGCI](https://www.graphclasses.org/) would be pretty neat. If it doesn't exist, it might be a fun student project to make one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classical reference on NP-completeness is Garey and Johnson's [Computers and Intractability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computers_and_Intractability), which contains a compendium of over 300 NP-complete problems, with links to papers proving their NP-hardness. The only downside is that the book is quite old, dating from 1979.